# Solution procedure for a system of trigonometric equations in two variables

Tags: trigonometry

i would like to know if there's a method for solving the following system using (or not) tan half angle substitution.

$$A\cdot\sin(\theta_1) + B\cdot\cos(\theta_1) + C\cdot\sin(\theta_3) + D\cdot\cos(\theta_3) + E = 0 ,$$
$$F\cdot\sin(\theta_1) + G\cdot\cos(\theta_1) + H\cdot\sin(\theta_3) + I\cdot\cos(\theta_3) + J = 0$$

I tried making tan half angle subs in mathematica and i ended up with four solutions for one of the variables. However the symbolic solution is quite big and unclear if it's a quartic function that is being solved in the background.